# Xcode 6 Swift partial auto complete methods

Tags: objective-c, swift, autocomplete, ios8, xcode6

When I use Objective-c I can write a method half way and then have the ability to continue to complete it after the fact.

For example if I want to make NSIndexPath

```
[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:5]
```

I can write

```
[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 in
```

and Xcode will initiate the auto complete options box for the second half of the method call.  And if it doesn't I can press esc to make the autocomplete options box show up.

however, with swift, there does not seems to be this feature.

```
NSIndexPath(forRow:1, in
```

If I type the above in swift, it does not autocomplete the desired method.

Is this feature available at all for swift?

Comment: Its a pretty often used object.  If you've a used uitableview you would have experienced it.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSIndexPath/indexPathForRow:inSection:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are Xcode plugins for this.  I like to use the fuzzyautocomplete because you can write partial methods.  It uses the same tool that "open quickly" uses to find these methods.

https://github.com/FuzzyAutocomplete/FuzzyAutocompletePlugin

You can also get this plugin (and more) from.

http://alcatraz.io

Answer (score 1):

I find that autocomplete for swift is really so far behind objective-c autocompletion. Hopefully they're going to improve it with each release, it's already a lot better than what it was a few months ago. On top of that swift error messages are let say 'more than confusing' at times.